# Isn't this an application(*) vulnerability? (Javascript and HTTP)

Tags: javascript, security, image, http, element

just wondering. Isn't this considered a threat? 
Let's say that 192.168.0.1 is a networkrouter with a administrationpanel on port 80. If you get a user to execute a similar snippet, wouldn't you be able to "bruteforce" the password? Considering network devices like networkrouters often feature default usernames and passwords.

```
<script>
function imgerror(data)
{
    alert('The following '+data.src+ ' failed due to wrong password/username.');
}
</script>

<img src="user:password@192.168.0.1/menu_button.gif" onerror="imgerror(this)">
```

menu_button.gif is in this case a button used in the administrationpanel - and protected by http basic authentication.

Comment: I haven't understood where is bruteforce on this code

Comment: It's not. But you can quickly implement javascript that adds image elements with different src's.

Comment: Not sure why you consider this a browser issue?

Comment: There are many more sophisticated ways of hacking a router's password. In my opinion, this dictionary attack is a good starting point for a learner. But I am not sure what you mean by 'getting a user to execute this snippet'. If you are going to brute force in the form of a dictionary attack, you will do it yourself. If you want the username/password for a particular admin, you will probably need to spoof the router or hijack DNS, and then phish out the password using a script similar to yours.

Comment: This attack is not a direct bruteforce, thus the reason for encircled quotation when I typed 'bruteforce'. I don't want to start feeding it an entire dictionary, my point here is that most routers and so-called networkadministrators don't care to change the default password. On many Linksys models for instance, default passwords are rarely changed. Not to mention what implications this would have for other networking units such as printers that judging by experience are powered by single GET requests to accomplish actions. My biggest concern at this moment is that you can't parse the response

Comment: As said by others, to be able to do that, you would need to be on that network first. If you can get on that network easily, why would you even bother with unprotected admin access to the router? This would only work with "prompt" password, not with a <form> password.

Comment: I think you need to rephrase that, Danosaure :-)

Answer (score 0):

It would only be a vulnerability if the developer/network administrator didn't care about security on their network.

Comment: A network administrator is in many cases the inexperienced public. Most routers I've accessed have admin/blank, blank/blank, admin/admin.

Comment: The times they are changing. Most ISP now deliver WAN routers with a non-trivial password.

Answer (score 0):

It is VERY old idea http://web.archive.org/web/20070315010517/www.spidynamics.com/spilabs/js-port-scan/

```
javascript:var i=document.createElement('IFRAME');i.src='http://192.168.1.1/';document.body.appendChild(i);void(0);
```

Try this one, and find crossnetwork warning in the iframe below*.

- requires aware UA :)

---

Techniques varies, the essence is the same - to execute script at the trusted side of firewall

Comment: I don't see how that's my idea. How would you check the HTTP response to be 200?

Comment: How would you prevent user from being alerted by sudden 401? :)

Comment: Like I stated previously, Firefox dies silently if the GET request for an image contains 401. On 200 though, I bet the onerror-event won't be executed. Please bare with me, as these are all assumptions from my side! And also let me add - "off the record" - that I don't want to get owned by a girl regarding this topic :(

Answer (score -1):

This is possible, even more sofisticated with some more lines of JS/Ajax (see [XXS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)).

What that means is you cannot trust NOBODY, even in your own network. If you cannot trust nobody and you have a basic security schema (as basic http authentification) you must use hard breakable passwords or if security is an issue (most private users do not know what security means at all) you MUST apply secure protocols.

If you use standard or blank passwords is leting the door open.